# How to disable all the children components in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to disable all the child components using hoc component. Loop through all the children and disable or hide the children

**Parent component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View} from 'react-native';

const Parent = (props) => {
  const { children } = { ...props };
  return (
   <View>
    {children}
   </View>
)
};

export default Parent;
```

**Children**

```
const Child = () => {
  return (
    <Parent>
    <View>
      <View>
      <Button title="foo" />
      </View>
     </View>
    </Parent>
  );
};
```

**HOC**

```
export const childrenWithProps = (children) =>
  React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    // Checking isValidElement is the safe way and avoids a typescript
    // error too.
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { disabled: true });
    }
    console.log(`child`, child);
    return child;
  });
```

How to disable the nested children in react.

Thanks!!

Comment: what do you mean by disable? hide or not make something clickable?

Comment: based on the user role

Comment: Just don't return the children if it doesn't meet the condition that you have. Then it is not going to render it. That is the way to hide/not display a component in React.